# Intializing dynamic arrays in c

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've created a dynamic array using malloc, while initializing it, I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
float* data_input = malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
data_input = {1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5};
```

Error:

```
model.c: In function ‘main’:
model.c:9:18: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
    9 |     data_input = {1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax in C in which `{1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5}` denotes an array.

In initializations, `{1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5}` denotes a list of initializers which may be used to initialize the elements of an array.

After `float *data_input = malloc(4 * sizeof *data_input);` (and checking that the return value of `malloc` is not a null pointer), you can initialize the array by initializing each element individually:

```
data_input[0] = 1.2;
data_input[1] = 2.4;
data_input[2] = 3.2;
data_input[3] = 4.5;
```

or you can copy the array from a *compound literal*:

```
memcpy(data_input, (float []) {1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5}, 4 * sizeof *data_input);
```

Answer (score 2):

This assignment statement

```
data_input = {1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5};
```

is incorrect in C.

Instead you could write

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

float* data_input = malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
memcpy( data_input, ( float [] ){1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 }, sizeof( float[4] ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 4 };
    
    float *data_input = malloc( N * sizeof( float ) );
    memcpy( data_input, ( float [] ){1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 }, sizeof( float[N] ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.1f ", data_input[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    free( data_input );

    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1.2 2.4 3.2 4.5
```

Comment: `( float * ){1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 }` will not compile. Nor will `sizeof float[4]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. It was a typo. I was in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use

```
float* data_input = malloc(4 * sizeof (float) );
memcpy( data_input, ( float [] ){1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 }, sizeof( float[4] ) );
```

But it has a drawback. Code duplication. Instead, you can do this:

```
float* data_input = malloc(4 * sizeof *data_input);
float tmp[] = { 1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 };
memcpy( data_input, tmp , sizeof tmp );
```

Or even

```
float tmp[] = { 1.2, 2.4, 3.2, 4.5 };
size_t size = sizeof tmp/sizeof tmp[0];
float* data_input = malloc(size * sizeof *data_input);
memcpy( data_input, tmp , sizeof tmp );
```

Note that the change from `sizeof (float)` to `sizeof *data_input` also is to avoid duplication.